# A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of fn:substring-after()

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Why am I getting this error:

> A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of `fn:substring-after()`

Does the `$arg1` in `substring-after()` function not allow a boolean expression as an argument?

```
<xsl:variable name="current" 
select="number(replace(substring-after(../wd:Function_Name
                                        [wd:Function_Name/@wd:Descriptor='Choose this' 
                                       or wd:Function_Name/@wd:Descriptor='Over this'
                                        ]
                                         /wd:Function_Name,
                                      '$'
                                      ),
                      ',',
                      ''
                      )
               )"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first argument of `substring-after()` is this XPath,

```
../wd:Function_Name[wd:Function_Name/@wd:Descriptor='Choose this' 
                 or wd:Function_Name/@wd:Descriptor='Over this']/wd:Function_Name
```

and it is selecting multiple nodes.  Refine it to select only a single node to meet the requirements given by the error message.  One way might be to select the first such node:

```
(../wd:Function_Name[wd:Function_Name/@wd:Descriptor='Choose this' 
                 or wd:Function_Name/@wd:Descriptor='Over this']/wd:Function_Name)[1]
```

but other, content-based approaches might work as well depending on your data.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown your data, and even if you had, we wouldn't know what you are trying to achieve, but my random guess is that what you really intended was

```
../wd:Function_Name/wd:Function_Name[@wd:Descriptor=('Choose this','Over this')]
```